# Timestamp format in data used with Create ML - Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, createml

I am poking around Create ML for the first time. I'd like to build a tabular model, and my dataset contains dates. Dates are in the format "2021-12-06 20:15:00" but Create ML identifies it as a String data type. Date could be important to the prediction though. What does my timestamp have to look like in order to be identified as such? Or can I change the data type somehow? I clicked around the GUI a bit, but couldn't figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Everything in double quotes is `String` so `"2021-12-06 20:15:00"` is indeed a string. To convert it to `Date` you need a `DateFormatter`.

Comment: @vadian What do you mean by DateFormatter? I'm uploading my data via a CSV file, which actually doesn't have quotes in it. Just added the quotes in the question.

Comment: CSV ist text aka string. I mean this [DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter)

Comment: @vadian so basically I can't do it via the GUI. I would have to write some code to do the model training and within that code I can use this class to solve my problem?